# Does every primitive digraph have a directed cycle?

Tags: graph-theory

A **digraph** is a directed graph.

A **directed cycle** or **simple directed circuit** is a directed circuit in which the only repeated vertices are the first and last vertices.

A **digraph is primitive** if its adjacency matrix is primitive.

A square non-negative **matrix** $A$  is said to be **primitive** if there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $A^k >0$ (all entries of $A^k$ are positive).

I need only the existence of a path with the structure $i_0 i_1...i_k i_0$ (sequence of distinc edges) with $k\geq 1$.

Comment: Simultaneously cross-posted to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3794785 . Please, do not do that.

Comment: Thanks for the observation it will not happen again

Comment: Does your definition of digraph allow for loops?
If no loops are allowed, then yes.  Since $(A^k)_{ii}$ is the number of walks of length $k$ from $v_i$ to $v_i$.

Comment: Thanks LouisD. Loops are allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
For all $i,j$, $(A^k)_{ij}>0$, so there is at least one walk of length $k$ from $v_1$ to $v_2$ and there is at least one walk of length $k$ from $v_2$ to $v_1$.  This closed directed walk which goes from $v_1$ to $v_2$ and then back to $v_1$ must contain a non-trivial directed cycle (i.e. a cycle of length at least 2).

Comment: Thank you very much.